# Web api enable CORS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I cannot access resources in [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) with [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax). I enabled [cors](/questions/tagged/cors) for all requests and added enable [cors](/questions/tagged/cors)attribute but still get error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present`... I also tried it with a particular website but still the same error. I am using Visual Studio 2013 .Net Framework 4.5.

I can access resourse with [html](/questions/tagged/html)sitting in the same website as [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api)

Code:

**[html](/questions/tagged/html):**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function GetAllStudents() {  
      $.ajax({          
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/studentsWebapi/students",
        success: function(result) {
          var list = $("#students");
          for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var students = result[i];
            list.append('<li>' + student.FirstName + '</li>');
          }            
        },
         error: function(xhr) {        
          alert("here " + xhr.responseText);          
        }     
      });
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="data"> here
    <ol id="students">
    </ol>
    <input type="button" onClick="GetAllStudents()"> click me </input>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works for me: `public HttpResponseMessage Request()
  {
   HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   response.Content = new StringContent("Some content...", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
   return response;
  }`.

Comment: thanks Danny Where do you call this?

Comment: That code is an example of API controller method that i use. Hmm Can you update your question with the code that you have?

Comment: sure i will thanks Danny

Comment: I was not able to get my c# code in acceptable format. So find it herehttps://github.com/kobosh/webapi

Comment: Your github link seems not updated.

Comment: I had a similar problem , I solved it by installing chrome extension for CORS and nuget package for CORS in Wep API and adding [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] to the controller

Comment: Thank Joe I did the same  : in global.asx i did enablecors; and added the attribute to the controller

Comment: Danny  I am trying to update it !

Comment: Danny  updated github  https://github.com/kobosh/webapi/tree/master/WebApiApplication

Comment: @kobosh I've made a demo by using the `HttpResponseMessage` class. The method is: `public HttpResponseMessage GetStudents()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, StudentRepository.GetAllStudents());
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return response;
        }`.

Comment: @Danny thanks i will try it.

Comment: @Danny Request.Create...... Error

Comment: @kobosh You need to see my answer. Probably the error you have is due to references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not execute your project due some issues but I did an example project to demonstrate a solution through the [**`HttpResponseMessage`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx) class.

You can use [**`HttpResponseMessage`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx) class. Then you can add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response headers when you need.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetStudents()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, StudentRepository.GetAllStudents());
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return response;
}
```

---

It's a good practice to keep a project structure.
I've made some changes in your project to make understable.

[image]

**1. WebAPI project.**

**App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs:** I've configured: `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` to make requests according this schema. Example: `http://localhost:60604/api/students/getstudents`.

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository/StudentRepository.cs:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using WebAPI.Models;

namespace WebAPI.Repository
{
    public class StudentRepository
    {
        private static List<Student> students = new List<Student> {
        new Student(){ StudentID=1, FirstName="Hass",LastName="Moh"},
         new Student(){ StudentID=2, FirstName="Hassan",LastName="Mohemm"},
          new Student(){ StudentID=3, FirstName="Hussan",LastName="Mohu"},
           new Student(){ StudentID=4, FirstName="Hessan",LastName="Moham"}
    };

        public static List<Student> GetAllStudents()
        {
            return students;
        }

        public static Student GetStudent(int studentID)
        {
            return students.Where(d => d.StudentID == studentID).First();
        }

        public static void RemoveStudent(int studentID)
        {
            var stu = students.Find(s => s.StudentID == studentID);
            students.Remove(stu);
        }

        public static void AddStudent(Student student)
        {
            students.Add(student);
        }

        public static void UpdateStudent(Student student)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

**Models/Student.cs:**

```
namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**API/StudentsController.cs:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebAPI.Models;
using WebAPI.Repository;

namespace WebAPI.API
{
    public class StudentsController : ApiController
    {
        public List<Student> Get()
        {
            return StudentRepository.GetAllStudents();
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage GetStudents()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, StudentRepository.GetAllStudents());
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return response;
        }

        public Student Get(int id)
        {
            return StudentRepository.GetStudent(id);
        }

        public void Post(Student Student)
        {
            StudentRepository.AddStudent(Student);
        }

        public void Put(Student Student)
        {
            StudentRepository.UpdateStudent(Student);
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            StudentRepository.RemoveStudent(id);
        }
    }
}
```

**2. WebApplication project.**

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data">
        <ol id="students"></ol>
        <input type="button" value=" click me" />
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function ()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:60604/api/students/getstudents",
                success: function (result)
                {
                    var list = $("#students"), student, html = "", len = result.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    {
                        student = result[i];
                        html = "<li>";
                        html += student.FirstName;
                        html += "</li>";
                        list.append(html);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr)
                {
                    alert("here " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, we can get the next results.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Danny I am using .net 4.5 and I get Error for Request.CreateResponse...... I needed to  new up  HttpRequestMessage Request   and only then my code could compile..... and when running it I get the same old error

Comment: my code at  https://github.com/kobosh/webapi/tree/master/WebApiApplication

Comment: You need this reference in your project: `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`.

Comment: added ref but still get error: public class StudensController : ApiController
    {

        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            
            HttpResponseMessage response =
                Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
                StudentRepository.GetAllStudents());
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return response;
        }


    }

Comment: @kobosh I just posted my demo on git so you can review it. https://github.com/dannyjhonston/WebAPI.